# Getting a 500 internal server error on Spotify API Token Retrieval

Tags: c#, asp.net, spotify

I'm working on getting the access token from the Spotify API but I am not able to retrieve it. I'm getting a 500 Internal Server Error when trying after being able to get the authorization code and following through with the process. Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SpotifyAPI
{
    public partial class Callback : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string code = Request.QueryString["code"];
            string state = Request.QueryString["state"];

            // Generate URL with authorization code
            string url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token?grant_type=authorization_code&code=" + code + "&redirect_uri=http://localhost:64270/Callback.aspx";

            // get Client ID and Secret
            string clientId = ((Site1)this.Master).getClientId();
            string clientSecret = ((Site1)this.Master).getClientSecret();

            // generate encoded header string for token request
            string preAuthorizationCode = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
            string postAuthorizationCode = Base64Encode(preAuthorizationCode);
            Debug.WriteLine("Post Authorization Code is: " + postAuthorizationCode);

            var webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
            webrequest.Method = "POST";

            WebHeaderCollection myWebHeaderCollection = webrequest.Headers;
            myWebHeaderCollection.Add("Authorization: Basic " + postAuthorizationCode);

            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

            Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
            string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
        {
            var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: does it get as far as the POST to Spotify or is that the line it breaks on?

Comment: line is breaking during the process before and after my modifications right on this line: HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webrequest.GetResponse();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the documentation

https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

You have to send

"grant_type", "code" and "redirect_uri" parameters as POST body. You are sending them as url parameters so Spotify gives an error.

Comment: thanks, changed these parameters to be in post body using string.Format. Then changed the original string url to "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token. Thought that would solve it but now it gives 400 error [Bad Request]. I checked my parameters and they're correct so I don't know what's up. Is there any way for me to better troubleshoot this, since the server response is so vague.

Comment: I decided to try another route and add the client id and client secret as post parameters in the body as well as the documentation suggested. I'm not sure what is the issue with encoding these two in base64 format but that seems to be the case.